# Having trouble debugging a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException on Application.Run

Tags: c#, vba, excel, com

I have an Excel function that I'm calling from C# as follows:

```
string result = xlApp.Run("'ExcelBook.xlsm'!mainFromBatch", 
                          "http://someSite/TestFile.xlsm",
                          false, 
                          "T:\\somePath");
```

When run, this raises an error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred
in BatchConverter.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800ADF09

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The function header for `mainFromBatch` is:

```
Function mainFromBatch(sourceBkPath As String, Flag As Boolean, _
                       Optional outputPathFromConfig As String) As String
```

When I put a breakpoint at this function header in the VBA code of `ExcelBook.xlsm`, the C# code raises the error, but the Excel breakpoint is reached and Excel pauses there, as though no error had occurred and it's ready to execute the rest of the code.

I'm able to use C# to call other functions from this workbook without a problem.

I tried Googling the HRESULT code but didn't find anything.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Is `mainFromBatch` located in a standard code module (.bas)? Also you may want to use a fully-qualified procedure name, too, in case there's 2 methods with the same name, in 2 different modules. I doubt that's your `COMException` though, but just sayin' ;-)

Comment: Can you call `xlApp.Run("'ExcelBook.xlsm'!mainFromBatch", ...)` from a VBA module?

Comment: @RubberDuck, yes, I can, and it runs successfully.  It's only when it's called from C# that this error occurs.

Comment: You'll get some hits when you google "excel" + "error 57097".  Something to do with forms.

Comment: @HansPassant, I looked at these results and didn't see anything related to my issue.  What should I be looking for?

Comment: You should be looking at the spreadsheet.  There's something wrong with it.  Delete stuff until the error disappears, the last thing you deleted caused the exception.